# copy all artifacts in a project to a new folder and create a module from them in IBM RDNG

Tags: ibm-doors, ibm-rational, rational-team-concert

I am working on IBM RDNG 6.0.4. I want to copy (duplicate) all the artifacts of a 
project into a single folder. Then create a module from it. Is there any trick to do it? My project has 1000+ artifacts stored in different folders.
Is there any API that can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue you do not have to use API, because you can do almost everything directly from UI.

1) Create a view that will display all the project requirements.

2) Click on the created view and select option "Edit attributes from view"

3) Select attribute "Folder" for a list of available attributes and change it value to folder of your choice. This will move all your requirements to a single folder.

4) Later you can add those requirement to module using folders filtering or views inside the module.

BTW. DNG does not support adding base artifacts (requirements) to complex structures (modules).

Hope it will help.